# Errors in creating a Webview2 sample app in UWP

Tags: c++, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I am following the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui2) and am able to successfully create the sample app sans webview till Step 5. From Step6 onwards, things go wrong.

This is the current content of my `MainPage.xaml`:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Webview2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Webview2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="ClickHandler">Click Me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

I added this block

```
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
```

as well as

```
<controls:WebView2 x:Name="WebView2" Source="https://bing.com"/>
```

inside the `StackPanel`, with the XAML now looking like

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <!--<Button x:Name="myButton" Click="ClickHandler">Click Me</Button>-->
        <controls:WebView2 x:Name="WebView2" Source="https://bing.com"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

This is what I see in the design editor

[image]

and upon building I encounter a lot of errors like

```
error C3083: 'Microsoft': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type (compiling source file MainPage.cpp)
error C3083: 'UI': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type (compiling source file MainPage.cpp)
error C3083: 'Xaml': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type (compiling source file MainPage.cpp)
error C3083: 'Controls': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type (compiling source file MainPage.cpp)
error C3646: 'WebView2': unknown override specifier (compiling source file MainPage.cpp)
```

essentially complaining about the usage of `Microsoft` in `::winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::WebView2`

I'm not sure what's exactly going wrong and can't find something similar to my issue. Would anybody know what's missing/needs to be changed to get the sample working?

Comment: Um, the page you linked gives instructions for creating a C# app, but somehow you ended up with a C++/WinRT app. In C++/WinRT, you need to [include the header files for namespaces you want to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/consume-apis#cwinrt-projection-headers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Errors in creating a Webview2 sample app in UWP

As Raymond Chen [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73311661/errors-in-creating-a-webview2-sample-app-in-uwp#comment129474231_73311661) the code is failing to include the C++/WinRT projection headers for `Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls`. After installing the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.UI.Xaml), please go to pch.h and add the following `#include` directives. For more info you could refer to A basic [C++/WinRT Windows UI Library 2 example (UWP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/simple-winui-example) document.

```cpp
#include "winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Automation.Peers.h"
#include "winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.h"
#include "winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.h"
#include "winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.h"
#include "winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.XamlTypeInfo.h"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but a quick question. Why aren't these pre-included in the pre-compiled header when creating a `Blank C++/Winrt (UWP)` app?

Comment: @zos Because you often don't need them. Those headers are *massive* (tens of thousands of lines of code), and including them introduces *significant* overhead in terms of compile times. If you need them, the compiler (or linker) will let you know.